# Git - Commits out of Master branch

Tags: git

My commits on the Git tree are out of the master branch. The result of this is when I push to my central repository the commits that are out of the master branch don't get pushed.

Here is a image of what I'm talking about:

[image]

What can I do to have the commits without branch inside the master branch?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter this into a command prompt/terminal: `git branch -f master HEAD`

This resets the `master` branch to `HEAD`, but since `master` already exists, it requires the force (`-f`) parameter.

After this, check out the `master` branch by executing `git checkout master` and then you can push your changes and your future commits will be made on the `master` branch.